# Creating a li with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a li element and am having trouble putting html in the text of the element. here is my code:

```
var li = $('<li/>')
  .addClass('moveTF')
  .attr('data-questionid', tfData[i].id)
  .attr('data-selected', tfData[i].selected)
  .text(question);
```

question contains:

```
<span class="question">Which of the following does <b><i>not</i></b> describe      Washington’s location?</span>
```

The li shows the html mark up.

How do I get the html to render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Html method rather than the text method.
Text will html encode everything passed to it.

```
 var li = $('<li/>')
      .addClass('moveTF')
      .attr('data-questionid', tfData[i].id)
      .attr('data-selected', tfData[i].selected)
      .html(question);
```

Answer (score 3):

To parse the string as HTML, add it as html, and you can attach all the properties to the element during creation :

```
var li = $('<li />', {
             'class' : 'moveTF',
             'data-questionid' : tfData[i].id,
             'data-selected' : tfData[i].selected,
             html : question
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to append it!

```
.appendTo("ul");
```